Problems with C file access arguments
I'm trying to learn C by making a basic daemon. I'm struggling to understand reading and writing files, since the arguments are correct to most posts and docs. My code is below:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include <libnotify/notify.h>
#define EXIT_SUCCES 0
#define EXIT_FALIURE_READING_FILE 1
#define EXIT_FALIURE_LIBNOTIFY 2

char *ProgramTitle = "styckynotes";
char *messages_array[] = {"this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set"};

int change_messgages(int array_number,char* message){
    if (array_number > 10){
        fprintf(stderr,"you are trying to write to a array number that doesnt exist, this would corrupt the memory please do not do that");
    }
    if (array_number < 10){
        char* intended_message= message;
        intended_message =  (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(intended_message)+1));
        messages_array[array_number-1] = intended_message;
        FILE myFile;
        myFile = fopen("messages.txt", "w");
        int i;
        if (myFile == NULL){
            printf("Error Reading File\n");
            exit (EXIT_FALIURE_READING_FILE);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            fprintf(myFile, "%d,", &messages_array[i] );
        }
        fclose(myFile);
    }
    return 0;
}

int signal_handler(void){
    //im counting from one since thats how an avarge user would experience it
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-1",note_pls(0));
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-2",note_pls(1));
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-3",note_pls(2));
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-4",note_pls(3));
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-5",note_pls(4));
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-6",note_pls(5));
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-7",note_pls(6));
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-8",note_pls(7));
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-9",note_pls(8));
    // rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-0",exit(EXIT_SUCCES));
    return 0;
}

note_pls(int pull_from){
    char* notification = notify_notification_new("reminder", messages_array[pull_from], "dialog-information");
    if (notification == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Got a null notify handle!\n");
    }
    notify_notification_show(notification, NULL);
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    signal_handler();
    bool notifyInitStatus = notify_init(ProgramTitle);
    if (!notifyInitStatus) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initialising with libnotify!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FALIURE_LIBNOTIFY);
        FILE* myFile;
        myFile = fopen("messages.txt", "r");
        int i;
        if (myFile == NULL){
            printf("Error Reading File\n");
            exit (EXIT_FALIURE_READING_FILE);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            fgets(myFile,696969, &messages_array[i] );
        }
        fclose(myFile);
    }
}

stickynotes.c: In function ‘change_messgages’:
stickynotes.c:25:14: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘FILE’ from type ‘FILE *’
   25 |     myFile = fopen("messages.txt", "w");
      |              ^~~~~
stickynotes.c:27:16: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘FILE’ and ‘void *’)
   27 |     if (myFile == NULL){
      |                ^~
stickynotes.c:32:17: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fprintf’
   32 |         fprintf(myFile, "%d,", &messages_array[i] );
      |                 ^~~~~~
      |                 |
      |                 FILE
In file included from stickynotes.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:357:38: note: expected ‘FILE * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘FILE’
  357 | extern int fprintf (FILE *__restrict __stream,
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
stickynotes.c:34:16: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fclose’
   34 |         fclose(myFile);
      |                ^~~~~~
      |                |
      |                FILE
/usr/include/stdio.h:184:26: note: expected ‘FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘FILE’
  184 | extern int fclose (FILE *__stream) __nonnull ((1));
      |                    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
stickynotes.c:76:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   76 |         fgets(myFile,696969, &messages_array[i] );
      |               ^~~~~~
      |               |
      |               FILE *
/usr/include/stdio.h:654:38: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘FILE *’
  654 | extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
stickynotes.c:76:30: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   76 |         fgets(myFile,696969, &messages_array[i] );
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              char **
/usr/include/stdio.h:654:69: note: expected ‘FILE * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  654 | extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
      |                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

Reading up on the docs, checking forum posts, changing types.

An error message of the form "Error reading file" in response to an fopen error is very confusing.  As a user, if I see "Error reading file", I think that the file was opened successfully but there was an error reading data.   Use perror.  (eg, if(fopen(path, ...) == NULL) { perror(path); exit 1; }

Always fix the first error first and then recompile. FILE myFile; myFile = fopen("messages.txt", "w"); The error message is reasonably clear. myFile should be declared FILE *myFile; but there's no point in seperately declaring and initializing. FILE *myFile = fopen("messages.txt", "w");

The reason for the compiler errors is because inside of change_messgages() you have declared the myFile variable as FILE instead of as  FILE*, like you have done for the myFile variable inside of main().

There are other problems with your code, too.
In change_messgages():

you are allocating a new char[] string that is the same length as the input message, but you are not copying the content of that message into the new string.  You could just use strdup() for that purpose.  But either way, if the specified array_number had already been set by a previous call to change_messgages() then you are leaking the memory you had previously malloc()'ed as you are not free()'ing it.  But, messages_array is initialized with char* pointers to string literals, so you have no way to know when you can safely free() the  existing strings in the messages_array.

the messages_array has only 9 elements in it, but your fprintf() loop is iterating through 16 elements.  You are exceeding the bounds of the array.

you are passing a char* pointer to the %d specifier in fprintf(). That specifier expects an int instead of a char*.  If you are trying to print the contents of the string that the char* is pointing at then use the %s specifier instead.


In main():

your file handling is inside the 1st if block, and so will be invoked only if notify_init() fails.

the messages_array has only 9 elements in it, but your fgets() loop is iterating through 16 elements.  You are exceeding the bounds of the array.

the messages_array is initialized with char* pointers to string literals, and you are not replacing those pointers before reading the messages.txt file, so you are trying to read data from the file into read-only memory. And worse, you are telling fgets() that it can read 696969 characters from the file, but you are not attempting to allocate any memory nearly that large.



Did you notice that all of the code after exit(EXIT_FALIURE_LIBNOTIFY); in main is unreachable, and therefore dead?  That's most of main.

thank you for telling me, I know this is probably dumb but i heard that daemons don't usually require memory freeing

@IbolyaVojtek Daemons are no different than other programs in that respect - if you've got memory that's intended to be in use for the duration of the program, you can probably just let the operating system free it on termination. But any memory you only temporarily need should be freed when you're done with it.

@IbolyaVojtek: since daemons typically run for a long time, it is more crucial than normal that they do not leak memory.
